# angularjs losing two way binding

Tags: angularjs

I have the following input that has two way binding to the model variable `IsChecked`.
When I change `IsChecked` in the controller, it changes on the UI html element tag and vice versa.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="modal-text" class="modal-text" data-ng-model="IsChecked"/>
```

However, when I introduce custom true/false values, two way binding seizes to work.
i.e `$scope.IsChecked = 1`  or `$scope.IsChecked = true` has not affect on the UI html element tag

```
<input type="checkbox" class="modal-text" data-ng-true-value="1" data-ng-false-value="0" class="modal-text" data-ng-model="IsChecked"/>
```

Any ideas appreciated. Thanks

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/waDHJ/33/

Comment: The jsfiddle will really help. I faced this issue and fixed it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion is that the true and false values are string values not integer values.

```
$scope.Option1Value = 1;
```

should be

```
$scope.Option1Value = "1";
```

please see the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/waDHJ/42/

Answer (score 3):

You should always have a '.' in your ng-models : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m